I'm running a server on the terminal with a node.js v-18 on a cPanel which only provides highest node.js v-14. How can I access the routes?
The current cPanel environment supports Node.js 14, which is not compatible with my application that requires Node.js 18+
I installed Node.js 18 using nvm on the terminal and it run without errors. but when I try to access the routes, I can only see the indexes.

If you need to access the routes publicly, set up a proxy from cPanel’s Apache/Nginx server to your Node.js server running on a custom port.
Configure the proxy via .htaccess, and then run nodejs server on a specific port.

Thank you for the fast response! For the record, I’m operating from a Node. js application in which the index.js file is situated at the src folder under the api directory. I am still attempting to ensure that this setup will not have issue with the proxy which is set in the cPanel. Could you provide a bit more detail on how to correctly set up the .htaccess file to ensure all routes are properly proxied to the Node.js server running on port 4466?
I appreciate your help!

Create or edit the .htaccess file in your public_html directory
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:4466/$1 [P,L]
This will forward all requests from your domain to your Node.js server running on port 4466.
Start your Node.js server on port
node your-server-file.js --port 4466.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
